# Angular http get call failling

Tags: angular

Please find the below url.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w4lj6q?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

I am using http module and  trying to get the data from json file but i am getting below error. can you please help somebody to fix the issue.

Error : errors.js:55 ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of things going wrong in the stackblitz.

1. The folder which contains the JSON is **apiDta** instead of **apiData**
2. Stackblitz is not returning the JSON even with the correct URL, rather responds with a HTML.

You can use [reqres](https://reqres.in/) to get a sample JSON.
Update the URL in `NameListService`

```
private _url: string = "https://reqres.in/api/users";
```

and update `AppComponent`'s `ngOnInit()`

```
this._nameService
    .getNames()
    .subscribe(res => { 
                          this.nameLists = res;
                          console.log(JSON.stringify(this.nameLists));
                      });
```

Comment: I can confirm, this works. Also nice find with reqres :)

Answer (score 0):

because you should add the `content-type` equal to `json` in the `http` `header` 
to make sure that the returned data format is `json` not `HTML`  as your code do